# Enable Bluetooth on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth

When I enter `Settings > PC Settings > Network > Flight mode`, the option for `Bluetooth` is disabled and grayed out. See the image below with the purple box. All `Bluetooth X` services are set to Automatic and running (like `Bluetooth Device Monitor`).

Running Windows 8.1 on an Acer Apsire S7, if relevant.

Any idea how to get Bluetooth enabled?

[image: Bluetooth disabled n Windows 8.1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't turn Bluetooth on or off](https://superuser.com/questions/746664/i-cant-turn-bluetooth-on-or-off)

Comment: Will check...daughter is using the computer at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your laptop doesn't have bluetooth (something unusual). Try going to the page of the laptop and downloading all drivers you don't have. Revise if Windows update has updates. If there is no solution, go to control panel > hardware and sound > device administrator (Under devices and printers). Then, search for the Bluetooth device. In case you don't have it, it means that your laptop doesn't have the Bluetooth adapter. If the device appears, right click it and then go to propierties > drivers > update driver. If it doesn't appears, you have the latest drivers and you are sure that your laptop has Bluetooth, contact the seller or Maker. Good luck!

Comment: It seems that your laptop has Bluetooth so, if the above answer doesn't works, search for the troubleshooter at the control panel and then select hardware and devices troubleshooter.

Comment: Good comments, though. Maybe it's something to do with the Bluetooth device in Device Manager...will check that.

Comment: Try it, I hope it works